# Sending post data on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to send post data (json) to webserver. It is very basic thing but in windows 8 api everything must be complicated :/ Sample provided by Microsoft is not working at all http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664/sourcecode?fileId=50955&pathId=797575364 scenerio 5 - it is sending something to server but no things that should be sent (maybe when i'm converting string to stream there are some problems...)

```
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes( data );
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Content = streamContent;
            request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true; 
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But I came up with another idea and this solution works (but...)

```
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();
            }

            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) 
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                    var answer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return answer;
                }
            }
```

As I said before, this solution has great disadvantage - server response can have http code 422 and then application crashes immediately. How I can check http response code using 2nd solution? (I'm not sure if this is even possible because it crashes on `request.GetResponseAsync` )

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the main body of your code with try-catch block and handle the `WebException` on a bad call. `WebException.Status` contains the status codes for why the request failed.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
try {
// Your code
}
 catch (WebException)
{ //error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have still some problems.

 catch (WebException ex)
        {
         if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError)
          Helper.debug("Send Fail");
                Helper.debug(ex.Status.ToString());
        }

And guess what? ex.Status.ToString() returns "ProtocolError" and WebExceptionStatus has no type like that oO None of the items in WebExceptionStatus is == to my ex.Status (if statement) Its weird... It looks that I must depend on the method .ToString :/